# How to parse xml string?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to set String to the TextView. But response which I getting is like
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"Fortune Life"</string>`

So it takes full string from xml to string but I want only double quoted content.i.e.,`"Fortune Life"`
What to do to parse xml string?

Comment: Perhaps `XPath` can come in handy here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Comment: Do you want the "Fortune Life" part or "http://tempuri.org/"?

Comment: @Sakhawat134 "Fortune Life" part

Comment: See my answer given below. If it does not solve your problem.please comment

Comment: @Sakhawat134 actually changes in response should be done by api developers right? is there any other way to parse this from our side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You Need to go to res > values > String.xml

you need to set your String in String.xml

[image]

[image]

In above image you need go to String xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">DocumentRecord</string>
<string name="your_title">your title</string>
<string name="your_url"><a href="your_website"></a></string></resources>
```

Comment: but it will be hardcoded value response will change every time so to add response their?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<string name="WebsiteTitle">"Fortune Life"</string>
<string name="WebsiteURL">"http://tempuri.org/"</string>
```

Then you can use string as R.string.WebsiteTitle or R.string.WebsiteURL.
To use string in TextView use android:text = "@string/WebsiteTitle" or android:text = "@string/WebsiteURL"